# How to read server side files and display all files by loop

Tags: javascript, java, php

Users will access a website and  upload some files to server.

I would like to use a forloop to loop through all uploaded images and display them.
I will update the imageList by timer ,for example ,update the image list every 2mins.

The  question is ,how I can loop through images files from web sever?Should I do this on client side or server side?

Thanks!

Comment: "The question is" ... no, your question is actually much much more complex than that. In the end you want somebody here to "help" you, to sit down with you and explain, teach you all the different options, to then pick one and implement that. Alas, please see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question ... meaning: your question is way too broad, as the solution requires many steps, and depending on requirements, there are many different ways to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! AS @GhostCat mentioned your question is pretty broad. If you need help architecting the solution - please provide all the constraints. If on the other hand, you need help with specific components which you have already decided for, specify which and how you are using them.

Answer (score 0):

> how I can loop through images files from web server?

Often, when you make an HTTP request to your server, your server will go get data from the database and return it as JSON to the client. This is how you access your data. In your example, you will likely be returning an array or a data object with an array of images in it.

> Should I do this on client side or server side?

What you are essentially asking is whether to use my server and database just for data persistence or also to contain business logic as well. A simple Google Search of something along the lines of, "Business logic on client or server" will get you pointed in the right direction. You'll see there are many considerations to this, and often one way versus the other is developer preference.

Comment: I know how to do with database, but I am making a simple application without database.I just know the file path of upload files.How can I achieve it without using database?